# How to verify that a polynomial is reducible and how to find its factors?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

The polynomial I'm working with is $f(x) = x^5 + x + 1$ in $Z2[x]$. I've tried finding its roots but $f(0) = 1$ and $f(1) = 1 (mod 2).$ I know that $f(x)$ is still reducible even though it doesn't have any roots, but I'm not sure how to verify this and then I'm uncertain how to then find its factors.

I assume that the factors $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ will need to be either of degree 2 and 3 or of degree 1 and 4.

Comment: A small hint: a root implies the existence of a degree one factor. Since there aren't any roots, there can't be any factors of degree one. A typography tip: if you want to write $\Bbb{Z}/2$, you can do this via \Bbb{Z}/2.

Answer (score 1):

One of the factors is quadratic, one cubic. We may demand the quadratic $x^2 + a x + 1,$ where either $a=0$ or $a=1.$ Well, if $a=0,$ we get a root, since $1^2 + 1 = 0 $ here.

Anyway, you do not do these all at once, you try to get one new coefficient at each step. So far the quadratic must be $x^2 + x + 1.$ At the moment, the cubic is some $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + 1.$ The product is
$$ x^5 + (b+1)x^4 + (b+c+1)x^3 + (b+c+1)x^2 + (c+1)x + 1 $$
while we want $x^5 + x + 1.$ The $x^4$ demands $b=1$ while the $x$ demands $c=0.$ We arrive at
$$ (x^2 + x + 1)(x^3 + x^2 + 1). $$
Looks good so far. Check it carefully!  Check for lack of roots in this field as well.

Comment: If one is experienced enough, one knows that $x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible quadratic over $\Bbb F_2$. Then just divide it into $x^5+x+1$.

Comment: I feel like I'm not getting it at all. If we set a=0 why did you set x=1? Also towards the end, $(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$ doesn't equal $x^5 + x + 1$ but it equals  $x^5 + 2x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 1$. What am I missing? Edit: Just answered my own question. It's because it's in Z2 so the $2x^4$ etc. equals $0x^4$.

Comment: @Gokira one of the things you are missing is that, in the field of two elements, $2=0.$ It is usually written $1+1=0,$ since there is no symbol $2$ in this field.  I guess your first question is about my claim that $x^2 + 1$ has roots in this field, namely $x=1.$

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you, I just figured it out as soon as I posted it. My first question was about the the roots in your first few sentences.

Comment: @WillJagy Sorry to be persistent but why did you not choose $x$ to equal $0$ but chose $x=1$? Is it because all you needed to do was just to prove that it has a root, and that whenever $x = 0$, the answer will always $= 1$ (so will never be a root). Is the goal to just simply find the root in the quadratic? Another question is why do you even need to find the root of the quadratic? My teachers have not been clear on this.